# How to generate 'a-z' and 'A-Z' randomly in a C++ program?

Tags: c++

Hi everyone I am trying to generate "A-Z" and "a-z" randomly in an array of size 1000. I have written the code to generate the uppercase letters i.e "A-Z" randomly but how do I also include the lowercase letters into them? I am fairly new to this can anyone help?

```
using namespace std;

int count(char vector[]);

void search(char vector[]);

int main()
{

   char vector [1000];

   char option;

   srand (time(NULL));

   for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)

   {
        vector[i] = rand() % 26 + 65;
        cout << " " << vector[i];

   }

   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If **you** wrote the code to generate A-Z, it should be trivial for you to generate a-z. This is exactly the same code. Because of that, it is unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: What you've shown is not a portable solution since it isn't guaranteed that the letters `'A'` to `'Z'` are contiguous or that 65 is equal to `'A'`.

Comment: I have to fill the array with lowercase and uppercase both randomly. It's just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use:

```
vector[i] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand() % 52];
```

So selecting random character from the c-string.

Easily customisable if you want to support 0-9 later for example, just make sure that hard coded length is correct (so using intermediate variable as `std::string` might then avoid that dependency).

Comment: Thank you Jarod42

Comment: I got it now. Thanks again.